# Can anyone explain how CRC works in this specific case?

Tags: crc

I am taught that given:

```
message M = 101001
polynomial C = x^3 + x^2 + 1 = 1101
```

I should add k bits to the end of the message such that the result P is divisible by C (where k is the degree of the polynomial, 3 in this case).

I can find no 3 bit combination (XYZ) that when appended to M satisfies this criteria.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm 5 months late to this, but here goes :

Perhaps, thinking about this by integer (or binary) division is counterproductive. Better to work it out by the continuous XOR method - which gives a checksum of `001`, rather than the expected `100`. This, when appended to the source generates the check value `101001001`.

Try [this](http://ideone.com/n19sD) `C` code to see a *somewhat* descriptive view.

I'm no expert, but I got most of my CRC fundamentals from [here](http://www.repairfaq.org/filipg/LINK/F_crc_v3.html). Hope that helps.